# Could you override a method from an abstract superclass, defining it in the subclass as an abstract method in Java?

Tags: java, oop, overriding, abstract-class

This may sound like a stupid question, but I really struggled for a long time to figure out the answer by my self. So is this possible?

For example:

```
public class SuperClass {
  public void methodToOverride(){
      System.out.println("Some text");
  }  
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
  abstract void methodToOverride();
}
```

Comment: Does it compile and run ok for you?

Comment: Yes, and the problem is that I don't have a logical answer why?

Comment: Would it make more sense if you added the `@Override` annotation above the `abstract void methodToOverride();` signature?

Comment: It's right there in [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.1): "An instance method that is not abstractcan be overridden by an abstractmethod."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to work you just need a few adjustments. First of all SubClass has to be abstract so it can have abstract methods.

Second, the methodToOverride method cannot have less visibility than it's parent's, so you have to set it public.

Then it should compile and run as expected. Here is an example:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public void methodToOverride(){
        System.out.println("Some text");
    }
}

public abstract class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    public abstract void methodToOverride();
}

public class OtherClass extends SubClass {
    @Override
    public void methodToOverride() {
        // new logic
    }
}
```

That being said, it's certainly an odd modelling...

Hope it helps!